# error in subprocess.Popen vs os.system

Tags: python, octave

I am trying to use subprocess.Popen rather than os.system, but am having a problem.  This seems so simple, that I am probably missing something obvious.  I am trying to call and run a script I have previously programmed in Octave (the Octave code works fine, and i do not want to have to spend the time to re-write this in NumPy, etc.).  I also do not want to keep Octave installed on this particular machine permanently.

This code works perfectly:

```
os.system('sudo apt-get install octave')
os.system('octave Documents/small_eig.m')
os.system('sudo apt-get remove octave')
```

This code, however:

```
subprocess.Popen('sudo apt-get install octave')
subprocess.Popen('octave Documents/small_eig.m')
subprocess.Popen('sudo apt-get remove octave')
```

Generates the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/ben.py", line 11, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen('sudo apt-get install octave')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you even read the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the command in "shell-mode". To do that, pass `shell=True` when calling `Popen`. Try:

```
subprocess.Popen('sudo apt-get install octave', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks much.  Sorry, I'm kind of a noob.  I read many comments that seemed to indicate that shell=True was unnecessary and seemed to be frowned upon for subprocess.Popen.

Comment: @BenjaminMull It's all about context.  Unfortunately, you will see many comments on this site stating "doing this is *bad*, so don't ever do it!", but if that were true in all cases it probably would not be an option.  In your case, `shell=True` is necessary, and that's OK.

Comment: I had the same problem with subprocess.call('sudo apt-get remove something'), I changed it to subprocess.call('sudo apt-get remove something', shell=True), works now!